# Grails where clause, why cant i search where id == id?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, where-clause

This has been bothering me for a bit.  The following query works:

```
Receipt.where{project.customer == customer}.list()
```

but this query throws an exception

```
Receipt.where{project.customer.id==customer.id}.list()
```

exception:

> Class
>       groovy.lang.MissingMethodException Message
>       No signature of method: receiptbucketserver.Customer.call() is applicable for argument types:
>   (receiptbucketserver.ReceiptHelperService$_tt__getReceiptsByCustomer_closure11_closure12_closure13)
>   values:
>   [receiptbucketserver.ReceiptHelperService$_tt__getReceiptsByCustomer_closure11_closure12_closure13@170130c3]
>   Possible solutions: wait(), last(), save(), any(), getAll(),
>   wait(long)

Comment: Can you try below code
`def receiptCriteria = {
  project {
    customer {
      eq('id', customerId)
    }
  }
}

def results = Receipt.findAll(receiptCriteria)`

Comment: In the first code snippet, you are comparing objects and in the second one, its properties for an object. It appears that **where** method only takes objects for comparison.